# Correct BeanFactory usage for retrieving bean by name, type and constructor arguments

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a number of prototype beans that all share a common superclass (`Foo`). All these beans have a common constructor taking one String argument.

I'd like to programmatically retrieve (and create) these beans based on the fully qualified bean name and String constructor argument. **Because this bean name comes from (external) configuration, I need to make sure only beans of the common superclass `Foo` can be constructed this way**.

Imagine the following:

- Interface `Foo`
- Bean `A implements Foo`
- Bean `B implements Foo`
- Bean `C implements Bar`

I now need a method that does this:

```
public Foo getBean(String name, String arg) {
    // Create a new instance of A or B (but not C) depending on name.
    // Pass args as the constructor argument
}
```

I managed to try and exclude the following already:

- `BeanFactory#getBean(String name, Object... args)` Too generic. Allows for the creation of **any** bean that matches, instead of type `Foo`.
- `BeanFactory#getBean(String name, Class<T> requiredType)`. Can't pass constructor arguments
- `ObjectProvider<Foo>#getObject(Object... args)`. Multiple bean matches. Can't select `A` or `B` by name

It seems what I need is something like `BeanFactory#getBean(String name, Class<T> requiredType, Object... args)` but this does not seem to exist.

Answer (score 1):

I have created something that works, but I still hope there is a better and cleaner solution available:

```
    public Foo getFoo(String name, String arg) {
        if (beanFactory.containsBean(name) && beanFactory.isTypeMatch(name, Foo.class)) {
            return (Foo) beanFactory.getBean(name, arg);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("nope!");
    }
```